# Can't find Appstream and BaseOs folders in RHEL-8-7-0-BaseOS-x86_64

Tags: linux, rhel, vmware, vmware-workstation

Im running Rhel 8 on my VMware Workstation 15 Pro. For some reason I'm not able to see the Appstream and Baseos folders When I tried running the `yum repolist` command, it displayed the 2 repositories but still can't find them in any folder

[image]

I also tried reconnecting the iso but it didn't work

Please help

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Repos are generally on remote sites; do you really want to mirror many GB of rpms, most of which you'll never use, on your local disk?

Comment: Yes, I want to make them available on my local disk. Is there any way I can do that.

Comment: RedHat provides [directions](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23016) after you log in with your subscription account.  There is also a package on [github](https://github.com/Tronde/poor-man-s-rhel-mirror) to mirror repositories but I have not tested the scripts. You need to set aside ~350GB disk space for the mirrors. You'll also want to update frequently to pick up new patches.

Comment: thank you for helping me